# SP initiated SAML logout response success, Idp does not log user out

Tags: c#, .net, saml, saml-2.0, adfs

I have created a SAML library in my app that creates an authentication request and is successfully logged in, but when it sends a LogoutRequest, the response shows:

"samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"

This should mean that the session has ended successfully at the Idp correct? I provide the session ID and the username of the logged in user in the logout request the same way as successfully specified in the auth request. However, when I attempt another login request, I am not prompted for credentials as though the session is still active. What would cause this? I do not have access to the Idp's ADFS server to view the logs and they are taking a long time to respond with them. Could I be missing something and still get a success message when it really wasn't a successful logout?

Comment: UPDATE: I found that it works as expected in IE, just not in Chrome. I believe it is related to this person's problem, and the received no response on a solution:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Sharepoint/en-US/ae94f395-3244-42aa-a722-e0a22e72e1c2/issue-when-using-firefox-or-chrome-to-logout-of-iag-when-using-adfs?forum=forefrontedgeiag